# Multipart/form-data request -- Uploading pdf is resulting in a blank file

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, multipartform-data

I have an objective to send a pdf file from one server to a REST API which handles some archiving. I am using .NET Core 3.1 and the [RestEase API library](https://github.com/canton7/RestEase) to help with some of the abstraction.

I have a simple console app that runs at a certain time everyday. The relevant code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestEase;

namespace CandidateUploadFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var apiClientBuilder = new ApiClientBuilder<ITestApi>();
                var api = apiClientBuilder.GetApi("https://my.api.com");
                var candidate = await api.GetCandidateByEmailAddress("tester@aol.com");
                var fileName = "tester.pdf";
                var fileBytesToUpload = await FileHelper.GetBytesFromFile($@"./{fileName}");
                var result = await api.UploadCandidateFileAsync(fileBytesToUpload, candidate.Data.First().Id, fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`apiClientBuilder` does some auth-header adding, and that's really it. I'm certain that bit isn't relevant.

`ITestApi` looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Models;
using RestEase;

namespace CandidateUploadFile
{
    public interface ITestApi : IApi
    {
        [Get("v1/candidates/{candidateId}")]
        Task<Models.Response<Candidate>> GetCandidate([Path] string candidateId);

        [Get("v1/candidates")]
        Task<Models.Response<IEnumerable<Candidate>>> GetCandidateByEmailAddress([Query] string email);

        [Get("v1/candidates")]
        Task<Models.Response<IEnumerable<Candidate>>> GetCandidates();

        [Post("v1/candidates/{candidateId}/files?perform_as=327d4d21-5cb0-4bc7-95f5-ae43aabc2db7")]
        Task<string> UploadFileAsync([Path] string candidateId, [Body] HttpContent content);

        [Get("v1/users")]
        Task<Models.Response<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers();
    }
}
```

It's `UploadFileAsync` that is really relevant here.

You'll note from `Program.Main` that I don't explicitly invoke `UploadFileAsync`. I instead invoke an extension method that basically wraps `UploadFileAsync` for the purpose of uploading the pdf using a `multipart/form-data` request. [This approach is what comes as a recommendation in the RestEase library docs.](https://github.com/canton7/RestEase#advanced-functionality-using-extension-methods). That extension method looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CandidateUploadFile
{
    public static class ApiExtension
    {
        public static async Task<string> UploadCandidateFileAsync(this ITestApi api, byte[] data, string candidateId, string fileName)
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "file",
                FileName = fileName
            };

            content.Add(fileContent);

            return await api.UploadFileAsync(candidateId, content);
        }
    }
}
```

So what will happen when my console app executes is: I will get a successful response from the upload endpoint, and the file on the archive server gets created, but it's blank.

It may be important to know that this *does not* happen when I send, say, a .txt file. The .txt file will save with the expected content.

Any insight would be helpful. I'm not sure where to start on this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to what I was doing in my `GetBytesFromFile` static helper method.

My static helper was using UTF-8 encoding to encode the *binary* content in the .pdfs I was uploading. However, it was working fine with .txt files I was uploading, which can be expected.

Lesson learned: there is no need -- and makes no sense -- to try to encode binary content before assign it to the multipart/form-data content. I just had to "pass-through" the binary content as-is, more-or-less.